# Regex parce string "address=/serv-1.mydomain.com/aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"

Tags: regex, bash

I need to get FQDN out of strings (dnsmasq config), such as:

```
address=/serv-1.mydomain.com/aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

to get only string **serv-1.mydomain.com**. How can I do that with (or without regex). Tnx in advance.

Comment: bash, and (sorry) no attempts (I don't know regex at all & can't ask google right question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ echo 'address=/serv-1.mydomain.com/aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd' | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
serv-1.mydomain.com
```

Through grep,

```
$ echo 'address=/serv-1.mydomain.com/aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd' | grep -oP '^[^/]*/\K[^/]*'
serv-1.mydomain.com
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final. `^` asserts that we are at the start and this `[^/]*` negated character class matches any character but not of `/` symbol, zero or more times.